# Taking transfer function out of real heating system

Tags: matlab, transfer-function, control-systems, pid

I have some king of heating system: heater (that I can control current for final power control) and a thermocouple (for measuring the temperature). I also have a device that can record temperatures from thermocouple.
I would like to take a transfer function of my system for my PID-alike algorithms testing in Matlab.
How can I do it? I am wandering if setting the heater for some low power and recording the temperatures is enough. How can I generate tf in matlab out of that king os step response?
I have full version of Matlab with all toolboxes (especially Control System Toolbox).